# Does ‘understood’ take ‘something’ as its direct object in this sentence?

Tags: objects, direct-objects

> She was not, I was told, in the hospital portion of the house with the
>   fever patients; for her complaint was consumption, not typhus: and by
>   consumption I, in my ignorance, **understood** something mild, which
>   time and care would be sure to alleviate. (Jane Eyre)

Does ‘understood’ take ‘something’ as its direct object, or is its object – it (consumption) – dropped? (If the former is right, what's the meaning of understood, then?)

Comment: Quite right: "I understood something mild by consumption" = "I understood consumption to be something mild"

Comment: @StoneyB So something is direct object (which implies consumption) and mild is objective complement, aren't they?

Comment: @Listenever: If you want to call something an "objective complement", I suggest you reserve that label for *"which time and care would be sure to alleviate."* It would be easier just to call *"mild"* an adjective modifying *"something"*. Basically, ***consumption is something** [mild, etc]* is Subject+Copula+Predicate.

Comment: *Mild* is simply an adjective modifying *something*. *Something*, *anything*, *everything*, unlike most pronouns, take modifiers, but they are usually post-posited: *something mild*, *anything red*, *everything hateful*. Another way of saying it is *some mild thing*, *any red thing*, *every hateful thing*. Informal speech tolerates *a little something*, but that is jocular and 'cute'.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You could rewrite **understood something mild** to **understood it to be something mild**.
Here **it** (the illness) is the subject. It's implied in your example.
"**something mild**" is a predicate adjective since we have an intransitive verb. It modifies the subject (the illness).

Comment: Er ... not quite. *Something* is a pronoun, not an adjective; *mild* is an adjective modifying *something*. In your rewrite, *it* is the subject not of the sentence but of the non-finite clause which is the direct object of *understood*, and *something mild* is (in Bas Aarts' terminology) a Subject-related Predicative Complement of that non-finite clause.

Comment: @StoneyB Regarding "something mild", you are correct. oops... Regarding "it", I did not specify the subject of what. My intention was that it was the subject of the clause.